# How to verify inf file installation

Tags: driver, inf

I have .inf file with a brother .sys file in the same folder.
they are drivers for plug and play device via usb .

When i try double click / right click the .inf file and pressing "Install"
It does not work, but if i try from "Device Manager" and choose to install manually with a given path - it installs OK.

How can i handle this, to make the inf file *installable*.. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a perl script tool called "chkinf"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543461(v=vs.85).aspx
to verify the correctness of inf files.

in addition in order to install inf properly it should have [defaultinstall] statement in it.

this is not the correct way to install a device driver.
the right way is to use a tool like, DPInst.exe
Guide is at
http://blogs.technet.com/b/svengruenitz/archive/2008/07/02/driver-installation-and-updating-made-easy-dpinst-exe.aspx

enjoy.